# React vibrate phone when timer hits a specific number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a count-down timer that when the user presses submit it starts counting down.
I have an `if` statement that is reducing the timer 1 second at a time and another function that starts vibrating the phone once the timer starts hitting 3 seconds. Problem is that the vibration starts immediately as soon as the count timer runs.

When I do `this.state.seconds` `==` or `===` `3` the vibration won't work.
If I do an assignment of `=3` then the timer count down runs fine but the vibration runs the entire time which means if the timer is 10seconds it'll vibrate for 10 seconds.

What am I doing wrong?

```
   resetTimer = () => {
    if(this.myInterval) {
      clearInterval(this.myInterval);
      this.setState({ seconds: this.props.exerciseData.rests });
    }
  }

  vibratePhone = () => {

    if (this.state.seconds === 3) {
      Vibration.vibrate(4 * 1000)
    }
  }

  startTimer = () => {
    this.vibratePhone();
    this.resetTimer();
    this.myInterval = setInterval(() => {

      if (this.state.seconds > 0) {
        this.setState(({ seconds }) => ({
          seconds: seconds - 1
        }))
        
      }
      else {
        this.resetTimer()
      }
    }, 1000)
  }
```

Where the timer gets called

```
<InputCard startTimer={this.startTimer}></InputCard>
```

Comment: What is the default seconds?

Comment: that gets pulled from redux which is `this.state.seconds`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you make a comparison only once when you press the button. You need to check it on every tick.

```
startTimer = () => {
  this.resetTimer();

  this.myInterval = setInterval(() => {
    this.vibratePhone();

    if (this.state.seconds > 0) {
      this.setState(({ seconds }) => ({
        seconds: seconds - 1
      }))    
    }
    else {
      this.resetTimer()
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

When you tried  `= 3`, it's not a comparison, it's an assignment that is always true, for example: `if (x = 5)` is true, that's why your phone vibrates immediatelly.